# iterate json array field

Tags: angularjs, json

I am having trouble with checkbox filtering an array field inside a JSON object/string in javascript.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="fruit">
    <div ng-controller="FruitCtrl">

        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('Red')"/> Red</br/>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('Orange')"/> Orange</br/>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('Yellow')"/> Yellow</br/>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="f in fruit | filter:colourFilter">
                {{f.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>

        Filter dump: {{colourIncludes}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my data:

```
 $scope.fruit = [
        {'name': 'Apple', 'colour': ['Red']},
        {'name': 'Orange', 'colour': ['Red','Orange']},
        {'name': 'Banana', 'colour': ['Yellow','Orange']}];
```

The original jsfiddle was based off of single item colours field, not an array of colours.

```
original:
{'name':'Apple','colour':'Red'}

my version:
{'name':'Apple','colour':['Red','Yellow']}
```

And this is how it **WAS** filtered:

```
$scope.colourFilter = function(fruit) {
    if ($scope.colourIncludes.length > 0) {
    var data = fruit.colour;
        if ($.inArray(fruit.colour, $scope.colourIncludes) < 0)
            return;
    }

    return fruit;
}
```

I am trying to filter like so:

```
$scope.colourFilter = function(fruit) {
if ($scope.colourIncludes.length > 0) {
var data = fruit.colour;
for(var i in data){
    if ($.inArray(data[i], $scope.colourIncludes) < 0)
      return;
    }

    return fruit;
}
```

Any ideas as to why I cannot find a match? I guess I am not scanning the arrays properly?

Comment: actually, the problem is with your data variable.

Comment: So my data array structure is not correct? I guess on the colour array definition?

Comment: look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i in fruit){
    fruit[i].colour.forEach(function(color){
        console.log(color); 
    });
}
```

This loop returns the items in the colour array one by one.

Basically, fruit.color is undefined b/c you're not specifying which index in the array you want to reference.

In other words, fruit[0].colour, fruit[1].colour ...etc  are valid.

Comment: `angular.forEach()` will be a better way to iterate through an object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't quite work for me, but this at least allows me to print the colors in each fruit:

```
$scope.colourFilter = function(f) {

        angular.forEach(f.colour, function(color){
        console.log("Color is: "+color);


    });

}
```